# ooyala embed code not populating video in modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, ooyala

I have an issue with the ooyala video embed code:

```
<script height="433px" width="770px" src="http://player.ooyala.com/iframe.js#ec=x0bjlycjpE7-g-D_2ZMGTcpUDGwEamhd&pbid=4441ed2a84e74b66b60ce980f20deb84"></script>
```

When I add this script in the main body it works fine. But when I add this script in a modal it does not populate the video. Here is code i have tried.

```
    <body>
      <div>
        <script height="433px" width="770px" src="http://player.ooyala.com/iframe.js#ec=x0bjlycjpE7-g-D_2ZMGTcpUDGwEamhd&pbid=4441ed2a84e74b66b60ce980f20deb84"></script> 
      </div>
      <div class="modal" id="category_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content about_us">
            <div class="modal-body">
              <script height="433px" width="770px" src="http://player.ooyala.com/iframe.js#ec=x0bjlycjpE7-g-D_2ZMGTcpUDGwEamhd&pbid=4441ed2a84e74b66b60ce980f20deb84"></script>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>
```

In the above code the 1st script load the video, but the 2nd script does not load the video. Is there any one who can suggest me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Does Ooyala have a javascript api? Sorry -- I am unfamiliar with this, but I think it does. I found this code snippet that someone has used within fancybox:

```
  'beforeShow': function() {          
      var videoPlayer = OO.Player.create('playerwrapper', 'R0ZjB2NTqDw3YRWba9RIpRnF6D9lRYKP', {});
     console.log(videoPlayer);
     videoPlayer.play();
  },
```

Note that 'beforeShow' is a fancybox callback function and your modal solution may have something different to use. Anyways typically loading in html for videos does not work in modal or lightbox type windows. And often javascript implementations need to be used after the modal is displayed to show the content.

I would try exploring this path.

Comment: You are right, but, here on my site the modal always shows up in the page. and the script is coming from the database using text editor. Kindly let me know if you find any other solution. thanx

Comment: @MuzamilAbbas Too late to comment, but I found out this solution works. I am too displaying the video in a BS modal.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde Thanks for your answer. Yes you are right this solution is working. But, I am getting a mix content from editor including the video script tag . So i think this is difficult to extract the right parameters to pass to this function.